# Getting constantValue: unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nspredicate, fetch

Getting this error with my fetch's predicate

```
2011-08-13 13:49:12.405 Codes[16957:10d03] NSlog Array: code BETWEEN {"06", "07"} 
2011-08-13 13:49:12.407 Codes[16957:10d03] -[NSCFString constantValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7464610 
2011-08-13 13:49:12.409 Codes[16957:10d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString constantValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7464610'

NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY code BETWEEN %@", [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.predicateFilterStart, self.predicateFilterEnd, nil]];:
```

NSLog shows `code BETWEEN {"06", "07"}`

Model Class for NSManagedObject with property `code`:

```
@interface MedicalCode : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * codeDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
```

FRC method: (ICD9Procedure is subclass of MedicalCode)

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ICD9Disease" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY code BEGINSWITH[c] %@", self.predicateFilter];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:myPredicate];    

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"code" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

EDIT:

All I need is a predicate that filters data.
I have a property of an entity called code that is in format like `55.534`.
I'm trying to fetch all data in a range, for example 50-60.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString *start = @"06";
NSString *end = @"07";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY code BETWEEN %@",
                      [NSArray arrayWithObjects: start, end, nil]];
NSLog(@"%@", pred);
```

That works for me:

```
2011-08-13 23:45:52.019 PredicateTest[18493:707] ANY code BETWEEN {"06", "07"}
```

so the error is probably in the properties.

FWIW, `constantValue` is a method of NSExpression. Not sure if that helps you.

---

I see you updated your code. Now it is very unclear where your error happened, since the code you orginally posted does not appear in the code you added, nor does it give additional info about the properties you are using.

And you say the error does not appear in the code you originally posted. It happens in a different piece of code, which you posted now, but it is not clear to me how that relates to the original code.

### Update

Apparently, from the discussion inthe comments, it turns out you need numbers, so do something like:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY code BETWEEN %@",
                      [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 50.0],
                        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 60.0],
                        nil]];
```

### Final solution

For those interested: the following apparently works.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY code BETWEEN %@",
                      [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                        [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 50.0]],
                        [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 60.0]],
                        nil]];
```

Comment: AS I said, please show us more: the types and the initialization of the properties you use. It could be the property code that is amiss.

Comment: What if you do: `NSString *start = @"06"; NSString *end = @"07"; ... arrayWithObjects: start, end, nil];` instead? (Comment out your real code and add this temporarily). Please also show your NSLog calls (not just the results). In other words: ***give more information so people can help you***.

Comment: Hey Rudy, I already posted much more code above when you requested. I get the same crash with the code you posted.

Comment: The NSLog you are referring to was when I just `NSLog@"NSlog Array:%@", filterPredicate);`.  The error always happens at `if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])`.

Comment: What other code do you need? I posted the fetch, the object class, etc.

Comment: When did I say that it doesn't appear in my original code?  The ordinal question I posted WAS the error, along with the fetch.

Comment: The fetch works perfectly when I remove the predicate, so I know something related to the predicate is causing the crash. I've used this predicate elsewhere in the app and it worked flawlessly, for some reason the format we are working with now is not working.  `NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY code BEGINSWITH[c] %@", self.predicateFilter];`

Comment: All I need is a predicate that filters data. I have a property of an entity called code that is in format like 55.534. I'm trying to fetch all data in a range, for example 50-60.

Comment: Then try NSNumbers instead of NSStrings. Or just try, to begin with, `... = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ANY code BETWEEN { 50.0, 60.0 }"];`.

Comment: I think `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ANY code BETWEEN { 50.0, 60.0 }"` did the trick!  Now can can I pass in my string numbers instead of 50.0 and 60.0?

Comment: It looks like it. Use `[NSNumber numberWithDouble: 50.0]`, or similar.

Comment: The code you posted in the update crashes the same way as before.  The only one I got to work was this `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ANY code BETWEEN { 50.0, 60.0 }"`.  I just need to know how to pass in my numbers.

Comment: When I NSLog them both, they seem to be identical, although one doesn't work.

Comment: AFAICT, and in my tests, both ways (literal string or %@ and array with 2 NSNumbers) resulted in the same predicate. I posted the code that worked for me. Hmmm... no, the predicate becomes: `ANY code BETWEEN {50, 60}`. Does it fail with that string?

Comment: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"ANY code BETWEEN { 50.0, 60.0 }"` works but `NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY code BETWEEN %@",
                      [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 50.0],
                        [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 60.0],
                        nil]];` causes the same crash we're working with.  Both look the same when I NSLog them, which is `ANY code BETWEEN {50, 60}`

Comment: Thanks I think that last predicate is working.  But how can I pass in my numbers (start and end) that are currently strings?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2449/discussion-between-faisal-and-rudy-velthuis)

Comment: If they are strings, use `[NSNumber numberWithFloat: [myString floatValue]]`. You can't pass the strings directly, since NSPredicate will put quotes around them.

Comment: One last thing, if I were to have a codes such as 555.1, 555.2, 55.3 etc, how can I tell the predicate to just search for all code where first 3 digits are 555.

Comment: Rudy are you still there? 1 question regarding this.  Please join me in the chat if you can,